# Quesiton about this epsilon-delta proof

Tags: epsilon-delta

This was posted in another question and below is the link.

> Prove Theorem 2.5(iii), namely, that if $f$
>   is continuous at $a$ and $λ$ is a scalar, then $λ⋅f$ is continuous at $a$ i.e. $$0<|x−a|<δ⇒|λf(x)−λf(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Here $|λf(x)−λf(a)|<\varepsilon$ is not equivalent to $|λf(x)−λf(a)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{λ}$ but rather to $|λf(x)−λf(a)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|λ|}$

My question is regarding the last inequality, shouldn't this be $|λf(x)−λf(a)|<\varepsilon$ instead?

[Epsilon delta theorem proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772483/epsilon-delta-theorem-proof)

Comment: reread yourself....

Answer (score 1):

I think the last part:

Here |λf(x)−λf(a)|<ϵ is not equivalent to |λf(x)−λf(a)|<ϵ/λ but rather to |λf(x)−λf(a)|<ϵ/|λ|

should read

Here |λf(x)−λf(a)|<ϵ is not equivalent to |f(x)−f(a)|<ϵ/λ but rather to |f(x)−f(a)|<ϵ/|λ|.

It is just saying that when you divide each side of the equation thorough by λ on each side, you can only do so by taking the modulus, |λ|. Otherwise if λ<0 the inequality would give a modulus (strictly positive) value on the LHS and a negative on the RHS which would clearly be wrong.

Comment: The modulus part I understood, but I want to know why there is still a lambda on the LHS. Because we divided epsilon by lambda, shouldn't the lambda on the LHS disappear.

Comment: Oh it seems you picked up on that too. Cheers

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know that we use MathJaX on this site to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.